# How to read PassportJS session cookie with ngx-cookie?

Tags: node.js, angular, session, cookies, passport.js

I'm learning Angular with a MEAN stack project. Full code is here: [Angular front-end](https://github.com/avilqu/mean-front-end), [Node.js API](https://github.com/avilqu/node-rest-api).

On the back-end, I use Passport authentication with the default session-based behaviour, and I have local, Google and Facebook strategies set up. Passport will insert user data in the session cookie, to be parsed and used by the front-end to display user name, email address, profile pic, etc.

So now in the back-end, what I need to do is retrieve the cookie and deserialize it, then write methods to use said cookie to get user data, as well as a basic isLoggedIn(), that would just check if a valid cookie is present.

To do that, I've tried both [ngx-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie) and [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) and have the same problem with both: I can create and read a cookie that I've created, but the 'session' and 'session.sig' cookies created by Passport remain invisible to the getAll method (and any get('session')).

All code handling that is inside [authentication.service.ts](https://github.com/avilqu/mean-front-end/blob/master/client/app/services/authentication.service.ts). Currently all methods are meant for a token-based auth, so I need to change them. Specifically, this is the method I use to test cookie handling:

```
public getCookies() {
    this.cookies.set('test', 'yay');
    console.log('test: ', this.cookies.check('test'));
    const allCookies = this.cookies.getAll();
    console.log('allCookies: ', allCookies);
    return allCookies;
}
```

The console output of that code shows only one cookie, 'test'. On the browser dev tools, I see there are two more cookies, 'session' and 'session.sig', that I want access to. But how?

Thanks!